# After opening UE5 just after compiling the following error appears (Linux)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

The error:

It appears after opening UE5 compiled from source code, had to export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1

````
libUnrealEditor-DesktopPlatform.so!FDesktopPlatformBase::InvokeUnrealBuildToolSync(FString const&, FOutputDevice&, bool, int&, FString&) [/home/bruno/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Developer/DesktopPlatform/Private/DesktopPlatformBase.cpp:681]
libUnrealEditor-DesktopPlatform.so!FDesktopPlatformBase::GetTargetsForProject(FString const&) const [/home/bruno/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Developer/DesktopPlatform/Private/DesktopPlatformBase.cpp:890]
libUnrealEditor-DesktopPlatform.so!FDesktopPlatformBase::GetTargetsForCurrentProject() const [/home/bruno/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Developer/DesktopPlatform/Private/DesktopPlatformBase.cpp:912]
libUnrealEditor-UnrealEd.so!EditorInit(IEngineLoop&) [/home/bruno/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Editor/UnrealEd/Private/UnrealEdGlobals.cpp:150]
UnrealEditor!GuardedMain(char16_t const*) [/home/bruno/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Launch/Private/Launch.cpp:158]
libUnrealEditor-UnixCommonStartup.so!CommonUnixMain(int, char**, int (*)(char16_t const*), void (*)()) [/home/bruno/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Unix/UnixCommonStartup/Private/UnixCommonStartup.cpp:264]
libc.so.6!UnknownFunction(0x2d30f)
libc.so.6!__libc_start_main(+0x80)
UnrealEditor!_start()```
````